# Laravel 5 one to many eloquent relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following database table structure

```
users
  id
  name

articles
  id
  about_id
  author_id
  text
```

And the following users :

```
1 Alex
2 John

And 2 articles one written by (author_id) John(2) about (about_id)
Alex(1) and other written by (author_id) Alex(1) about (about_id)
John(2).
```

My question is how should does the model of articles table named "Article", should look like for the relationships mentioned below.
I would like to access the article object for retrieving author object like :

```
$article = Article::find(1);
$article->author;
```

And to retrieve the object of the user that the article is about like :

```
$article = Article::find(1);
$article->about;
```

I have to mention that i have only two models : Article and User.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Article model should look like this

```
class Article extends Model {
    public function author() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'author_id');
    }

    public function about() {
        return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'about_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: i have only 2 Models : Article and User, that means the id from column about_id is a user too(App\User) , not a different object

Answer (score 0):

You can also use hasMany

```
class Article extends Model {
    public function author() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\Author", 'author_id', 'id');
    }

    public function about() {
        return $this->hasMany("App\About", 'author_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use App\User;
use App\Article;

class Article extends Model {

    public function author() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Article::class, 'author_id');
    }

    public function about() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'about_id');
    }
}
```